# Object-fit doesn't work with fixed width and height

Tags: html, css, object-fit

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://dialog.localhost/upload/postomat/04a/04aeacfed49dd7eda5f469f57b822f7f.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

In my opinion, the picture should shrink to fit into the block, but this does not happen. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

specify your image to the `block`

specify both height and width:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

use `object-fit: cover` or `object-fit: fill`

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```